# paste together specific columns from many .gz files

Tags: bash, text

that uncompressed have the same number of lines, and the same number of columns.

All files are located in the same dir.

Is it possible to pullout every 5-6 column from every file and paste them together without having to dump temp files?

Something like

```
for i in *.gz
do
   gunzip -c $i |cut -f5-6 >$i.tmp;
done

paste *.tmp
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a command line to evaluate and use bash process substitution to avoid tempfiles:

```
command=paste
for i in *.gz; do
    command="$command <(gzip -cd $i | cut -f5-6)"
done
eval $command
```

Comment: That is indeed an interesting way to do it. Should work fine, as long as the number of files isn't too many (you're using several processes and a handful of file descriptors for each file). Also, beware of quoting in $i.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *.gz ; do
  printf '_fn %s\n' "$f" 
  gunzip -c "$f"  
done | 
  awk 'END {
    for (i = 0; ++i <= m;)
      for (j = 0; ++j <= fc;)
        printf "%s", (d[j, i] (j < fc ? OFS : RS))    
    }
  $1 == "_fn" {
    fn = $2; fnr = x; ++fc
    next
    }
  { 
    d[fc, ++fnr] = $5 OFS $6
    fnr > m && m = fnr
    }' OFS='\t'
```

Comment: Great job... I don't know `awk` very well, but I finally worked it out. A good learning experience for me (I know awk a bit better now :) thanks... It only limitation seems to be how much RAM is available, which would equate to the the size of the output file plus a relative percentage overhead for the array structures ... I like it :) ... +1 in fact, and **+** a few more in spirit :)