# cut different columns into different file in one pass

Tags: text-processing

I got some huge gz files. And I need to extract the different columns and put these into different files.

I can of cause make multiple passes of the file, and cut out the different columns each time.
But is is possible to do in a single pass.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [paste together specific columns from many .gz files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895921/paste-together-specific-columns-from-many-gz-files)

Comment: Why have you asked the same question twice? Or, alternatively, how is this one supposed to be different?

Comment: Other question was for dumping to a single file, this is for different files

Comment: derobert, how is it the same when it's almost exact opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
awk '{print $1>"f1"; print $2>"f2"; }' < input
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do it in one pass. This is a solution for an arbitrary number of
columns.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i > "file"i }' file1 file2 file2
```